Memory usage for multiple tabs pointing to the same module
I am creating a lightweight Shiny app in R using modules. I have a requirement that that I can access the same 'page' (or more accurately the same module) using multiple tabs. The REPREX below shows this idea in practice. In this case there are 3 tabs each with a uiOutput with a unique identifier, but they all link to a module with a single id. My question relates to how this affects memory usage. Is this creating three instances of the module (1 in each uiOutput) or do the uiOutputs just all point to single object? If the former, then I would probably implement the module using a conditional panel, but if the latter then this is a workable and scalable solution.
library(shiny)

# Define the module UI
my_module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textOutput(ns("module_text"))
  )
}

# Define the module server logic
my_module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$module_text <- renderText({
      paste("This is content from module with ID:", id)
    })
  })
}

# Define the UI
ui <- navbarPage("Navbar Menu Example",
                 navbarMenu("Menu",
                            tabPanel("Tab 1", uiOutput("tab1_ui")),
                            tabPanel("Tab 2", uiOutput("tab2_ui")),
                            tabPanel("Tab 3", uiOutput("tab3_ui"))
                 )
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Create UI outputs for each tab, pointing to the same module
  output$tab1_ui <- renderUI({ my_module_ui("shared_module") })
  output$tab2_ui <- renderUI({ my_module_ui("shared_module") })
  output$tab3_ui <- renderUI({ my_module_ui("shared_module") })

  # Call the module server function once with the shared ID
  my_module_server("shared_module")
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)


I would not recommend using the above pattern, as you are creating three elements with duplicated IDs which results in invalid HTML.
Please enable devmode() and you'll get a client side error:

This is the resulting HTML:
<div class="tab-content" data-tabsetid="9309">
        <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Tab 1" id="tab-5520-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
          <div id="tab1_ui" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite"><div id="shared_module-module_text" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite">This is content from module with ID: shared_module</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" data-value="Tab 2" id="tab-5520-2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
          <div id="tab2_ui" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite"><div id="shared_module-module_text" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite">This is content from module with ID: shared_module</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" data-value="Tab 3" id="tab-5520-3" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0">
          <div id="tab3_ui" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite"><div id="shared_module-module_text" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output" aria-live="polite">This is content from module with ID: shared_module</div></div>
        </div>
      </div>

This btw. is what shiny's modules are intended for - define a pair of functions (server and ui) to create repetitive elements without having to care about namespace conflicts. It seems you are trying to undermine this mechanism. Accordingly I'd suggest: either you call the module multiple times with unique ID's (and accept the overhead) or you don't use modules in the first place, which allows you to apply the same server code to multiple outputs.
The only advantage of the linked approach regarding memory usage is, that you are saving the memory needed to hold the separate render functions. Even when applying the same render function to multiple outputs it will get called for every output:
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Navbar Menu Example",
                 navbarMenu("Menu",
                            tabPanel("Tab 1", textOutput("module_text1")),
                            tabPanel("Tab 2", textOutput("module_text2")),
                            tabPanel("Tab 3", textOutput("module_text3"))
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$module_text1 <- output$module_text2 <- output$module_text3 <- renderText({
    print("renderText running")
    paste("This is content")
  })
  # run all at once, otherwise the output object will be suspended (not executed) when it is hidden on the web page.
  # lapply(list("module_text1", "module_text2", "module_text3"), outputOptions, x = output, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Below please find an example on how to track the memory usage (modified version of my post here):
library(DT)
library(pryr)
library(shiny)

current_mem_used_pretty_size <- reactive({
  invalidateLater(1000L)
  format(structure(mem_used(), class="object_size"), units="auto", standard="SI")
})

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("start_new_session"),
  textOutput("memory_used_session_start"),
  textOutput("memory_currently_used"),
  div(actionLink("close_session", "Close this session"), style = "margin-bottom:20px;"),
  navbarPage("Navbar Menu Example",
             navbarMenu("Menu",
                        tabPanel("Tab 1", DTOutput("example_table1")),
                        tabPanel("Tab 2", DTOutput("example_table2")),
                        tabPanel("Tab 3", DTOutput("example_table3"))
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$close_session, {
    session$close()
  })
  output$start_new_session <- renderUI({
    clientData <- reactiveValuesToList(session$clientData)
    link <- with(clientData, paste0(url_protocol, "//", url_hostname, ":", url_port, url_pathname))
    div(a("Open new session", target="_blank", href = link, title = link), style = "margin-top:10px;")
  })
  output$memory_used_session_start <- renderText({
    mem_used_pretty_size <- format(structure(mem_used(), class = "object_size"), units = "auto", standard = "SI")
    paste0(mem_used_pretty_size, " memory used after starting this session (", session$token, ")")
  })
  output$memory_currently_used <- renderText({
    paste0(current_mem_used_pretty_size(), " memory currently in use (", format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE, digits = 0L), ")")
  })
  onStop(function(){
    cat("Stopped session", session$token, "\n")
    # gc(verbose = TRUE)
    print(mem_used())
  })
# example code ------------------------------------------------------------
  example_data <- reactive({
    data.frame(replicate(100L, runif(10000L)))
  })
  output$example_table1 <- output$example_table2 <- output$example_table3 <- renderDT({example_data()}, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Furthermore, please check RStudio's profiling capabilities based on profvis.

Didnt know about devmode. Thanks for pointing that out!

I also didn't know about devmode(). Very handy! Modules are often touted as a superior way to create Shiny apps but I guess this is just an occasion where modules have a limitation compared to the standard way. My question would still apply to the example in the link that you provide. Even when not using modules, does having three output uiobjects point to the same rendered output triple the memory used on either the client or the server side? Or is it just three pointers pointing to the same thing -> no increase in memory usage?

@TheDza memory-wise it won't make a big difference, unless you are using extensive render functions. Please see my edit.

Nice one @ismirsehregal. Thanks for the detailed answer. Great tips re devmode and the memory tracking code too. I ran your code as is and tracked the memory and then I ran it but with only 1 example_table output and the memory usage was almost exactly the same.
